# Xampp LAMP server: localhost:80 requires a username and password

Tags: localhost

I would  installed xampp in my system but when i try to run my localhost following message will appear "The server localshost:80 requires a username and password.please help

Comment: On a fresh install?
You're just opened localhost from your web browser?

Answer (score 1):

More to the point would be an explanation of the consequences of using or not using a password and account. For example, why does it look for a username and password for localhost? Who else will use the localhost server.

From observations of the network trying to break into the Apache Server, one would be well advised to keep off-line when using the local host or use Listen localhost:8080 in htpd.conf.

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP has no passwords set by default.

Try running

```
/opt/lampp/lampp security
```

and follow the directions.